# How to split strings inside object and push them into array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reactjs

I receive an object and each time it different quantity of strings different every time

```
Object {
    key_id: 7, 
    key1: "String1, String2", 
    key2: "String1, String2, String3", 
    key3: "String1, String2", 
    key4: "String1, String2";
    …
}
```

I want to receive

```
Array = [{key_id: 7, key1: "String1", key1: "String2" ...}]
```

or

```
Array = [{key_id: 7, key1: "String1", "String2" ...}]
```

I need that to make this strings separated to make from them separated links.
I am making it on ReactJs with JSX/Babel ES6

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: You want one object inside an array, or multiple objects?

Comment: you can not have multiple same key names in one object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Object#entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to convert to an array of [key, value] pairs, and `Array#map` them:

```js
const data = {
  key_id: 7, 
  key1: "String1, String2", 
  key2: "String1, String2, String3", 
  key3: "String1, String2", 
  key4: "String1, String2"
};

const result = Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: typeof value === 'string' ? value.split(', ') : value
}));

// an array with multiple objects
console.log(result);

// A single object:
console.log(Object.assign({}, ...result));
```

Note that `Object#entries` is not part of ES6, and is not supported by IE and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Updated the code to change each property to array element.

```js
let data = {
  key_id: 7, 
  key1: "String1, String2", 
  key2: "String1, String2, String3", 
  key3: "String1, String2", 
  key4: "String1, String2"
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
    data[key] = typeof data[key] === 'string' ? data[key].split(', ') : data[key];
});

console.log(data);
```